# Inflating ConstraintLayout crashes on some devices

Tags: android, xml, android-constraintlayout

I have an xml-layout that works on some devices but crashes when inflated in others (xml-code only partly shown):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_record_audio"
android:minWidth="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
>
```

Inflating the layout works fine on some devices but causes an `InflateException` on others.

I found the culprit in my xml-file:

```
<!-- Causes InflateException on some devices: 
     android:minWidth="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major"  -->
```

Unfortunately, after removing the line that causes the `InflateException`, `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` does not work anymore.
The `layout_height` always gets rendered as if it was set to `"match_parent"`. Any ideas about what's going on and how to solve this?

ADDED FOR CLARITY

Here's how I call the Dialog:

```
fun showRecordAudioDialog(view: View, categoryId: String, detailId: String) {
    val dialog = RecordAudioDialogFragment.newInstance(categoryId, detailId)
    dialog.show(this@DetailsActivity.supportFragmentManager, "RecordAudioDialog")
}
```

In my RecordAudioDialogFragment:

```
    // Use the Builder class for convenient dialog construction
    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity, style.CustomTheme_Dialog)

    val inflater = activity.layoutInflater
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(layout.dialog_record_audio, null)
```

Comment: You should set its constraints from the designer.

Comment: @AIK That would be including `android:minWidth="@android:dimen/dialog_min_width_major"` and crash! Back to square one!

Comment: Is it possible that [dialog_min_width_major](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.dimen.html#dialog_min_width_major) may not be defined for certain devices? This dimension was introduced in API 11, so are these devices <API 11?

Comment: @Cheticamp You might be right but the problem does not seem to be related to API version. The latest device where it crashes runs on API 26 (Android O). It does not crash on my tablet running Android M.

Comment: A simple test would be to define your own value for the dimension to see if that resolves the crash problem.

Comment: @Cheticamp Could you please elaborate a bit further on how to try that? I wonder how a `minWidth` property can somehow define the behavior of `layout_height` .

Comment: I should have read your question a little more carefully. So, you delete the troublesome line but the (dialog?) height goes to the full screen. Can you be more specific about how the dialog is created and maybe give the XML for it?

Comment: @Cheticamp I edited my question to (hopefully) clarify what I'm actually doing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some strange reason `android:layout_height` does not work if `android:minWidth` is not set.

So, in `dimens.xml` we need to add a line like
 `<dimen name="dialog_min_with">500dp</dimen>`

and then add `android:minWidth="@dimen/dialog_min_with"` to our `mylayout.xml` file.

This is how the head of the layout.xml file looks now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/constraintLayout_record_audio"
android:minWidth="@dimen/dialog_min_with"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">
```